# WPF (or WinForm) WebView doesn't opens local URL (NotFound 404 error)

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, microsoft-edge

**Introduction**

Microsoft recently released the WebView control (`Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls` package), that allows developer to include a Webbrowser which uses **Microsoft Edge** to render website in WPF/WinForm application. This new control is intended to replace the old `WebBrowser` control which is using IE engine.

More info [here](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/)

**My problem**

The browser doesn't seems to work with local network website urls. Even if I use ip address, I always get the `NotFound` (404) on my `WebErrorStatus` (but no exception), but in the stand-alone Edge browser it works well. However, external urls (google...) are working fine.

I've tried to check if the embeded browser uses proper proxy settings, but i've got no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security purpose, the WebView control disables private network capabilities by default. You must enable it explicitly.

```
wvc.IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled = true;
```